# I'm curious about the features of .ui and .qml design files

Tags: qt, qml

When designing a GUI in Qt, I usually work in .qml format.
If you look at several programs, you will see many programs working in .ui format.
When designing in Qt, I wonder if the difference between .ui and .qml is special. ex) speed, optimization, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Qt has 2 ways of creating ui: [QtWidgets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html) (that `.ui` file) and [QtQuick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-index.html) (the `.qml` file).

QtWidgets module is C++ code, that `.ui` file is an xml file format used by the designer, but it is compiled by a tool called `uic` into C++ code.

QtQuick is the module that brings QML language into the mix, so you create ui in [QML language](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html) and you can still use C++ for the "back-end" tasks.

Both can have advantages and disadvantages depending on what you need, there is no generic one better than the other answer.